# Download local repository jar dependency files through maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I was not able to download one jar through maven so i have created one local repository and downloaded jar manually and then added to pom by using system scope

```
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>c:\\bdh\gdhs</systemPath>
```

but i requires the dependencies of the local repository jar. what should i do then? manually adding each and every dependency jars is not a good solution it seems
someone help please..

Comment: what is the library name u need to install?

Comment: What was the problem that it hand't worked? Error messages? Correct coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use system scope.

Install the downloaded file to local repository.

**If you have both pom & artifact**

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DpomFile=<path-to-pomfile>
```

To have its dependencies also resolved correctly - so not to add every dependency by hand - you need the pom.

**If you do not have the pom**

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=**group-id** \
    -DartifactId=**artifact-id** -Dversion=**version** -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Without pom the dependencies of installed artifact can not be resolved automatically and you need to manually install them (preferably with pom).

Then just add it as dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>***group-id**</groupId>
   <artifactId>**artifact-id**</artifactId>
   <version>**version**</version>
</dependency>
```

Refer [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) for more details