# How to resolve maven dependency manually, if I only have source code of it?

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, tycho

In my case, all of the depencies are resolved by tycho p2, however I switched from the master branch to a maintanence branch, and for some dependencies, the version range is different, some of them are just not in the eclipse repo.

I am sure that I need one repo, that has it's source on github. It could be compiled without issues. There is a maintanence branch for that dependency.

Am I able to compile the dependency and put it somewhere, where maven identifies it as dependency? If so, then where should I put it?

Comment: When you have jar compiled take a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47218238/download-local-repository-jar-dependency-files-through-maven. There are of course plenty of other examples also if you do a little bit googling.

Comment: Alright, thanks, that's good for a start.