# javax.jnlp as maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, jnlp

Using JNLP (javax.jnlp) in one java project, I reaized that it is not part of the normal JDK.
As it is a Maven project I would like to add it as a dependency to my POM.

The one dependency I found working is:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jnlp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jnlp-api</artifactId>
      <version>8.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/javaws.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>
```

But depending on a system path looks bad to me - really bad.
`system` is marked as deprecated here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html
Is there no other way?
Getting it from repositories as an reasonable up to date version (java 8)?
Or what would be the clean way?

Comment: Best would be to use an oracle maven repository https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9010 (registration needed)..afterwards using a repository manager would be the best idea..

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47218799/6413377) of mine. It will not help you to get the latest version easily but helps you to get rid of `<scope>system</scope>`.

Comment: There is an older version at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jnlp/jnlp/1.5.0.  Do you need more than what that provides?